# How to implement Voice Activity Detection in .NET Maui

Tags: .net, audio, maui

I am trying to get a Voice Activity Detection for .NET Maui in Android. Its needed to detect how long a user of the app is talking and when he has stopped talking. So the audio recordning is in real time.

All I can find is the normal Speech Recognition for .NET Maui but no libraries for VAC which can be used. Does anyone know a good open-source library which can be used to detect how long the user is talking in real time?

Comment: It can't do that for Maui.